# How do you generate static pages that read local data in a NextJS 13 application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I completed their blog tutorial, and it works fine. It creates dynamic pages from .md blog posts that are stored locally. Beautiful.

But I am running into a wall trying to make what seems like a simple modification.

I want to add search and filter to the blog posts. For that, we need to "use client". And the `fs` module does not work on the client. Their docs recommend using the `fetch` API, but that doesn't work on local files, as they aren't URLs.`getStaticProps()` is deprecated when using the /app router, I believe in older versions I could have run that, and run my `fs` functions at build time

This is one of the two functions that need to run.

```
export async function getPostData(id: string) {
  const fullPath = path.join(process.cwd(), `/public/posts/${id}.md`);
  const fileContents = fs.readFileSync(fullPath, "utf8");


  // Use gray-matter to parse the post metadata section
  const matterResult = matter(fileContents);

  const processedContent = await remark()
    .use(html)
    .process(matterResult.content);

  const contentHtml = processedContent.toString();

  const blogPostWithHTML: BlogPost & { contentHtml: string } = {
    id,
    title: matterResult.data.title,
    date: matterResult.data.date,
    tags: matterResult.data.tags,
    contentHtml,
  };
  // Combine the data with the id
  return blogPostWithHTML;
}
```

So I believe I either need to run these functions at build time, to generate static pages for each blog post (there's only 2). Or I need some client side way to read local files. That would be as simple as ANYTHING that can turn a .md into a string!

(I cannot do SSR, as I am generating the whole site statically, and simply hosting it on S3 with a cloudfront distribution)

Comment: Not particularly familiar with NextJS, but to turn a local path into a file URL, you can use `const url = new URL(absolutePath, "file://").toString();`. If their recommendation in the docs _is_ true and you _can_ fetch local files, then this would be the URL to use. (`toString` not needed)

Comment: Good idea, should have thought of trying that, but no that doesn't work, blocked by NextJS

Answer (score 0):

Solved by running the utility functions that use ‘fs’ in the parent, server component, then passing the converted text to the searchable (client) blog section, where the dynamic blog post pages can accept the props and render with SSG.

There are disadvantages to this, you need to run it on all Markdown files at once, rather than getting only what is needed, or currently displayed.

But it works!